# Bool state is incorrect when retrieved from param server

Tags: ros, parameter, param-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code is:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh_private("~");     
bool state=false;

nh_private.param<bool>("state", state, "false");
```

It turns out the "state" is "true". Why???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193716/bool-state-is-incorrect-when-retrieved-from-param-server/) by [GuoliangLiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1015/guoliangliu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-29**:
Following the answer from @kmhallen, this would seem to be expected (and correct) behaviour (you're just using the wrong type for your default value). Perhaps change your topic title to reflect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
template<typename T>
void param(const std::string& param_name, T& param_val, const T& default_val) const;
```

From the function prototype, param_val and default_val are both the template type, in this case bool.

The string value "false" is a pointer to the characters 'false' which is non-zero. This is interpreted as true when used as a bool. Try without quotes around false;

```
nh_private.param<bool>("state", state, false);
```

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuoliangLiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1015/guoliangliu/) on 2014-10-07**:
great! thinks!

**Comment by [GPereira](https://answers.ros.org/users/57062/gpereira/) on 2020-07-27**:
I am getting the following error on ROS Noetic. Any ideas?

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘bool’
   nh.getParam<bool>("dissemination_rules", dissemination_rules, true);
```

**Comment by [dwyackzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/110355/dwyackzan/) on 2022-07-11**:
The `getParam` method does not have a default setting parameter (and does not require templating) like the `param` method.

So if you want to be able to set a default value then use the `param` method:

```
nh.param<bool>("dissemination_rules", dissemination_rules, true);
```

Or if you want to just use `getParam` without setting a default value:

```
nh.Param("dissemination_rules", dissemination_rules);
```